# How to change "2022-01-17T21:00:00" from string to 2022-01-17T21:00:00 Date Type in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert "2022-01-17T21:00:00" in string to Date Type 2022-01-17T21:00:00.
This is what i tried

```
 String dateInput="2022-01-17T21:00:00";

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS");

 data.setOutput(sdf.parse(dateInput));
```

It was converting to 2022-01-17T15:30:00.000 instead of 2022-01-17T21:00:00.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert something to itself?

Comment: i want to change the type, String to date

Comment: please change "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS" to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

Comment: let me try once, Thanks!

Comment: I have changed it and tried, But the same output 2022-01-17T15:30:00.000.

Comment: Since Java8 use `LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-01-17T21:00:00");`

Comment: I think you need set time zone for SimpleDateFormat.  Example: sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Comment: @ViettelSolutions `SimpleDateFormat` should not be used for modern java.

Comment: sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));This has worked 
Viettel Solutions
.Thank you all for the swift help.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Can you explain about this?

Comment: @ViettelSolutions Since Java8 there has been introduced the java.time package. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Comment: @ScaryWombat tks, let me see

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. I got `Mon Jan 17 21:00:00 JST 2022`. A [mre], please?